# Specify command parameters for shortcut in Setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, compact-framework, setup-project

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but here is my situation.

I have a deployment project that installs the Primary output of a compact framework console application to \Program Files Folder\MyApp and creates a shortcut to the Primary out in Windows Folder\StartUp.

In the shortcut that is created in Windows Folder\StartUp I'd like to pass a Command Line Parameter to my exe so that I know it has been run because the OS has just started rather than the user manually running the .exe

I can't seem to find anyway to specify a command line parameter, the only properties on the shortcut are (Name) , Folder and Target.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own shortcut file (e.g. "foo.lnk" - [format is well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx)), then add that as a file to the setup project instead of using the project's built-in shortcut-creating mechanism.

Comment: I was able to create a shortcut using this method but I still couldn't add it to the deployment project. when trying to add the file Visual Studio wouldn't throw up any errors or messages it just didn't add the file.

Answer (score 0):

I manually created a shortcut but was unable to add it to the deployment project.

In the end I added the manually created shortcut (.lnk) to the main application project and set the build action to "Content".

Then within the deployment project I was able to add "Project Output -> Content files" to the Windows Folder\StartUp folder to finally achieve getting a shortcut with a command parameter to be installed to the windows start up folder on the device.